# Циклом вывести значения многомерного массива

Tags: php

Нужно вывести из большой переменной значения, но вместо них выводяться "1", как исправить?

```
print_r($result);
for($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++ ) {
    echo($result[$i] -> $first_name).'<br>';
    echo($result[$i] -> $last_name).'<br>';
    echo($result[$i] -> $uid).'<br>';
    echo('=========================================='.'<br>');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r($result);
for($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++ ) {
    echo $result[$i]['first_name'] . '<br>';
    echo $result[$i]['last_name'] . '<br>';
    echo $result[$i]['uid'] . '<br>';
    echo('=========================================='.'<br>');
};

foreach($result as $el){
    echo $el['first_name'] . '<br>';
    echo $el['last_name'] . '<br>';
    echo $el['uid'] . '<br>';
    echo('=========================================='.'<br>');
}
```